# Replace entire appsettings.json before build and deploy in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, appsettings

**Scenario**
I have two repos with similar API-code funtionality but for two different type of objects.

Sence the functionality is similar, then i have focused on developing one of them and the thought is to reuse it for both APIs for these both object types.

now i have
Repo 1 for objectType 1 with it's own appSettings.JSON for just its object type
Repo 2 for objectType 2 with it's own appSettings.JSON for just its object type

Now i want to create a pipeline to build, and publish the API to the cloud without needing to write the code twice, once for objectType 1 and once for objecttype 2

**Question:**
can i create an azure pipeline for Build and deploy as:

Pipeline from Repo 1:   Check out the source code from Repo 2 (which has the latest code) and use appsettings.JSON from self repo (Repo 1)

Comment: Please take a look at Alberto Maghini's answer to see if it is helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please mark it as a correct answer. Others who meet the same question will appreciate you much.

Answer (score 0):

That's feasible if you use the `YAML` pipeline schema.
As you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops), you can check out multiple repositories.
If you have multiple checkouts steps, please only pay attention to the [paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) where they will be stored as the agent will create subfolders.